# How to truncate datestring in pandas to_json datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following code:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"a" : [datetime(2017, 1, 3), datetime(2017, 2, 4)], "b" : [2, 4]})
>>> df
           a  b
0 2017-01-03  2
1 2017-02-04  4
>>> df.to_json(orient = "index", date_format = "iso")
'{"0":{"a":"2017-01-03T00:00:00.000Z","b":2},"1":{"a":"2017-02-04T00:00:00.000Z","b":4}}'
```

Is there a way to truncate the date time strings in JSON to just say `"2017-01-03"` instead of `"2017-01-03T00:00:00.000Z"`?

Answer (score 0):

You can cast them to string and then export:

```
df.astype(str).to_json(orient = "index", date_format = "iso")
Out[45]: '{"0":{"a":"2017-01-03","b":"2"},"1":{"a":"2017-02-04","b":"4"}}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert to the appropriate string first:

```
 df.a = df.a.dt.date.astype(str)
```

This gives `'{"a":{"0":"2017-01-03","1":"2017-02-04"},"b":{"0":2,"1":4}}'`

Alternatively, you could call `.replace('T00:00:00.000Z','')` on your json string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) or [`dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.date.html) with `astype` for convert to `string` with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
print (df.assign(a=df['a'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).to_json(orient = "index"))
{"0":{"a":"2017-01-03","b":2},"1":{"a":"2017-02-04","b":4}}
```

---

```
print (df.assign(a=df['a'].dt.date.astype(str)).to_json(orient = "index"))
{"0":{"a":"2017-01-03","b":2},"1":{"a":"2017-02-04","b":4}}

print (df.dtypes)
a    datetime64[ns]
b             int64
dtype: object
```

Or if no problem change original `dtype` of datetime column:

```
df['a'] = df['a'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
print (df.to_json(orient = "index"))
{"0":{"a":"2017-01-03","b":2},"1":{"a":"2017-02-04","b":4}}

print (df.dtypes)
a    object
b     int64
dtype: object
```